# Extraneous blank lines in output of PHP terminal program

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP. I am writing a file program, but before I could properly use the logic and code it, I got stuck here.

I am writing this PHP program in Linux Ubuntu Terminal. Please don't worry about what I am trying to do with the program. Just helping me understand the error itself would be a great help.

I have a PHP file(a.php) with the following contents:

```
<?php
$input=fopen($argv[1],"r");
$col=$argv[2]-1;

while(!feof($input))
{
        $x=fgets($input);
        $array=explode("\t",$x);
}
fclose($input);
?>
```

Now when I give this in the command prompt:

```
php a.php 1
```

I should be getting nothing as an output, but I get around 3 to 4 blank lines. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Do you have blank lines before `<?php` and after `?>`? Make sure you don't

Comment: You could also try removing the `?>`

Comment: I get a whole bunch of errors when I try to do what you did.... Make sure you have error reporting on...

Comment: Yep, that's what it should do. `php a.php 1` -- 1 is boolean so it'll just throw the `fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` warning.

Comment: Also, the `$col` varible is defined but not used anywhere. Also, as @Neal said, turning error reporting on might help :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot guys, Hey @Arda, u r correct. I had some blank lines after ?> . I will this in mind in future

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be your file path that is $argv[1].
Try this

```
$filePath = 'Your file path here';
if( !@$input = fopen($filePath, "r") ) {
  die("Could not open $filePath");
}

while(!feof($input))
{
        $x=fgets($input);
        $array=explode("\t",$x);
}
fclose($input);
```